# Get location of iTunes track Applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I have the code below to convert a track in iTunes but when it is trying to get the location of the converted track it errors:

```
tell application "iTunes"
        set theFiles to the selection

        repeat with theTrack in theFiles
            with timeout of 120 seconds
                set finish of theTrack to 30
                set theSecondTrack to first item of {convert theTrack}
                set theSecondPath to location of theSecondTrack
                say "RingtoneDude has converted the song."
```

Error:

> error "Can’t get location of {file track id 3942 of library playlist
>   id 2208 of source id 65 of application \"iTunes\"}." number -1728 from
>   «class pLoc» of {«class cFlT» id 3942 of «class cLiP» id 2208 of
>   «class cSrc» id 65}

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you´ve misunderstood what `location` does. Revealing iTunes tracks in Finder is actually quite a bit more complicated but luckily has already been done by Doug Adams, as explained in [this article](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/spotlight.php).

You should definitely check out the rest of dougscripts.com as he has already created a script (for what I assume is your goal) called "make ringable" and released it under GNU GPL [here](http://dougscripts.com/475)

=== EDIT:

Oops, I´m sorry, looks like `location` *does* work, just not how I expected, try the following with one file selected:

```
tell application "iTunes"

tell item 1 of the selection to set theLocation to {get location}
tell application "Finder" to reveal theLocation

end tell
```